# Closing dismissViewController doesn't fire the viewWillAppear

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, modal-dialog

I have a view which opens a modal seque View.

I open this view with this code:

```
- (IBAction)openInfopage:(UIButton *)sender;
{
  [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Infopage" sender:self.view];
}
```

I close this View with:

```
- (IBAction)closeView:(id)sender { 
  // old version: 
  //[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

  // my new version:
  [self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];       
}
```

When the modal is closed, I want to update the view with the new datas the modal view generated.

I use `[self.tableView reloadData];` to update, but where can I put this code, so it will start?

I try the viewWillAppear, but this isn't called when I close the modal view.

Comment: Can you tell me what you have written in the viewWillAppear method? Like the code in the method. Because the viewWillAppear show be called when the modal view is dismissed. I can try to help if i can see the code.

Comment: The viewWillAppear is empty at the moment. 
I want to use the  [self.tableView reloadData]; 
But because the viewWillAppear: isn't firing, I only have a NSLog @"Test"; inside the viewWillAppear.

Answer (score 1):

I always put these things in a delegate-protocol. So just insert this to your modal-viewcontroller.h:

```
@protocol MyDelegateProtocol <NSObject>

@optional
-(void)modalFinished;

@end

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, weak) id <MyDelegateProtocol> delegate;

@end
```

And in the .m call this:

```
if(_delegate) [_delegate modalFinished];
```

When you are done. In the presenting ViewController you have to omplement this:

```
<MyDelegateProtocol>
```

after the @implementation line. And implement the delegate-method -(void)modalFinished. In this method you can do your refresh. And of course set the delegate property from the modal-viewcontroller to self in the presenting view controller.

EDIT:

```
MyViewController mvc = ...;
MyViewController.delegate = self;
[self presentViewController:...];
```

and if you present via segue:

in prepareForSegue:

```
MyViewController *mvc = segue.destinationViewController;
mvc.delegate = self;
```

Comment: Delegate properties should be declared as weak to prevent retain cycles.

Comment: I try it, like in Benjamins example. But I have a problem, I don't kow how I "implement the <MyDelegateProtocol>" in the ViewController.

Comment: I'll try it this way: 
@interface DetailTableViewController : UITableViewController <MyDelegateProtocol>

But I think the last problem is, how I set the delegate property to self

Comment: Yeah, how you tried it, should work.
You have to set the delegate property when you create your instance of the ViewController you want to present. I update the code.